# Unable to get values in ftl from value stack in custom Result Type

Tags: templates, freemarker

I am unable retrieve value from value stack in FTL file. Here is the code.

Action class holds a property called 'name'

```
private String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String execute(){
    setName("From value stack .. ");
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

FTL code:

```
${name}
```

Custom result Type doExecute Method

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

String templatePath = "/ftl";
ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
configuration.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(context, templatePath);
configuration.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());

Template template = configuration.getTemplate("sample.ftl");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
template.process(ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack(), out);
```

I am passing the value Stack which contains recently executed Action as well. But FTL is throwing an exception

**Expression name is undefined on line 1, column 3 in sample.ftl**

I tried with passing session instead of value stack and I could get the value in FTL.

Please suggest me a way to get values from Action class to FTL  from value stack.
Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to get values from recently executed Action Class. Just change the last statement as follows

```
template.process(invocation.getAction(), out);
```

Thanks